# jQuery updating localstorage from json file

Tags: jquery, json

I'm stuck in this jQuery localstorage update problem. I'm new in code and I don't have a clue of doing this.

What I'm trying to do, is when I change my jsonfile value, I want the localstorage updating this value automaticaly. I think i miss something here.

Here is my code, if someone can help me.

```js
//start point
$(document).ready(function() {
  let jsonData = {};
  let ls = false;
  jsonData.href = window.location.href;

  function getLs() {
    if (window.localStorage["local"]) {
      ls = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("local"));
      if (ls) {
        $.each(ls, (key, val) => {
          $("#" + key).text(val);
        });
      }
    }
  }
  getLs();

  // get language from flag click
  $("[data-lang]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let lang = $(this).attr("data-lang");
    let jsonFile = `lang/${lang}.json`;

    // get key:value from json files
    $.getJSON(jsonFile, data => {
      $.each(data, (k, v) => {
        // set json file to the localStorage
        if ("localStorage" in window) {
          let jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
          window.localStorage.setItem("local", jsonData);
          $("#" + k).text(v);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Welcome To My Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body id="bg-img-home">
    <header>
        <div class="flags">
            <button class="lang fr" data-lang="fr"></button>
            <button class="lang en" data-lang="en"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-btn">
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
        </div>

        <nav class="menu">
            <div class="menu-branding">
                <div class="logo"></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="menu-nav">
                <li class="nav-item current">
                    <a href="./" class="nav-link" id="home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="./about.html" class="nav-link" id="about">About me</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="./work.html" class="nav-link" id="work">My work</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="./contact.html" class="nav-link" id="contact">Contact me</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main class="home">
        <h1 class="lg-heading">
            <span id="firstname">John </span>
            <span class="text-secondary" id="lastname">Mauduit</span>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="sm-heading" id="position">Web Developper</h2>
        <div class="icons">
            <a href="https://github.com/johnmauduit/Epitech_Coding_Academy" target="_blank">
                <i class="fab fa-github fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/johnmauduit/" target="_blank">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lang.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

There is a bit of my json:

```
{  
  "home": "accueil",
  "about": "à propos de moi",
  "work": "mon travail",
  "contact": "me contacter"
}
```

Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your localstorage, whenever you make changes to json.

You have to do this each time when you make you updates json  and if want it to get updated in localstorage. It can't be done automatically.

```
localStorage.setItem('local', JSON.stringify(yourObject));
var item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('local'));
```

Comment: Ok, so it's a bad idea to do that for a multilingual static portfolio website? Maybe i can use session storage instead?

Comment: It will be better to read json from backend on server and update your json (if important) from client to server(backend). If json is not large enough in size and not important(security reasons etc) you can store it in localStorage or sessionStorage. Hope you know when to store it in localStorage or when in SessionStorage. GoodLuck.

Comment: Thank's Ahmad, there is no problem with security, it's just for my portfolio, and it's static. I know for the backend way, but i want to do it simple, client may have acces to multilingual and content update.